# how to get url variable value in my controller

Tags: angularjs

My url is: http://192.168.1.4:8081/theme11#/createAd

I want to remove all if conditions and assign the "theme number variable" directly to the $scope.banner variable. I have tried $routeParams but it is not showing any value. I am a fresher and have basic knowledge of how angularjs works. Please help me.

```
            var myStr = $location.absUrl(); 
            if (myStr.indexOf("theme11") != -1){
                    console.log ("THEME11  ");
                    $scope.banner = "theme11.jpg";
                    }else if(myStr.indexOf("theme2") != -1){
                        console.log ("THEME2");
                        $scope.banner = "theme2.jpg";
                    }else if(myStr.indexOf("theme3") != -1){
                        console.log ("THEME3");
                        $scope.banner = "theme3.jpg";
                    }else if(myStr.indexOf("theme4") != -1){
                        console.log ("THEME4");
                        $scope.banner = "theme4.jpg";
                    }
                    else{
                        $scope.banner = "default.jpg";
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split

```
var themeName = $location.path().split("/")[3]
'http://192.168.1.4:8081/theme11#/createAd'.split("/")[3]
```

themeName contain

```
themeName = "theme11#"
```

Then

```
theme = themeName..split("#")[0]
theme= "theme11"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I wasted whole day.. you saved my evening..:)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, try this:

```
var myStr = $location.absUrl(); 
var number = parseInt(myStr.replace((location.protocol+'//'), '').split('/')[1].replace('theme', ''));
$scope.banner = 'theme' + number + '.jpg";
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3Lkencyg/